# Making Java methods generic

Tags: java, generics

Suppose I have these abstract classes:

```
class BasicObject {
    private String name;
    // getter and setter here
}

class BasicObjectExplorer {
    void explore(BasicObject basicObject) {
        // now some actions regarding name property
    }
}
```

Now you have AdvancedObject extending BasicObject and AdvancedObjectExplorer extending BasicObjectExplorer, How to use generics to reuse code of Basic classes and write just functionality regarding new properties added to AdvancedObject?

Thank you for help.

Comment: Why do you need generics for that? Wouldn't simple inheritance work for what you want?

Comment: THat's not what generics are for.

Comment: @Marcelo "When all you have is a hammer..."

Comment: Just to nitpick, I would use `Base` or `Abstract` as a prefix, rather than `Basic`.  And, yeah, you might want to look at rephrasing your question so that generics are even needed.  The way it's worded right now, Marcelo's right: you would just use simple inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are asking that you want your abstract class to be base of class handling generic classes .

Then

```
public abstract class AbstractObjectExplorer<T> {

    void explore(T basicObject) {
        // now some actions regarding name property
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Foo extends  BasicObjectExplorer<String> {
}

public class Bar extends  BasicObjectExplorer<Double> {
}
```

Comment: If you're gonna let your BasicObjectExplorer explore any object, then it might be better named as ObjectExplorer.  Just a thought.

Comment: Would saying `...class AbstractObjectExplorer<T extends BasicObject>` be right, then?

Comment: I don't know if the question is more confusing or this answer.